# OSX Automator: Cannot localize an Obj-C action

Tags: macos, localization, automator

I have an OSX Automator workflow that contains a custom Obj-C action. It works, but I am not able to localize it. My test action is:

```
- (id)runWithInput:(id)input fromAction:(AMAction *)anAction error:(NSDictionary **)errorInfo
{
    NSArray *contactStrings = (NSArray *)input;
    NSString *name    = contactStrings[0];
    NSString *address = contactStrings[1];
    NSString *comment = NSLocalizedString(@"IMPORTED", nil);
    NSString *output  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@, Address: %@, Comment: %@", name, address, comment];
    return output;
}
```

I have a localized `Localizable.strings` file with a base and a German localization.
Base (without comments):

```
"IMPORTED" = "Imported from OSX service";
```

German (without comments):

```
"IMPORTED" = "Über OSX-Dienst eingelesen";
```

The problem is that when the Automator script is executed, the comment string is output as `IMPORTED`, e.g. the localization does not work at all.
What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:
`NSLocalizedString(...)` is a macro defined in `NSBundle.h` as

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

This means that by using this macro, the `Localizable.strings` files are searched **in the main bundle of the Automator application**, **not the bundle of the Obj-c action**!!! This is also documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/HowAutomatorWorks.html).
The bundle of the Obj-c action is obtained by `[self bundle]`.

I thus replaced the wrong line

```
NSString *comment = NSLocalizedString(@"IMPORTED", nil);
```

by

```
NSString *comment = [[self bundle] localizedStringForKey:@"IMPORTED" value:@"" table:nil];
```

and everything works.
Hope this helps somebody else also!